# Should I use wampserver on Windows Server 2012 R2 or install apache, mysql etc. on the server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, windows-server-2012

I am setting up a server for the first time ever (no prior experience) and got the static IP setup for it no problem.  The next step is to setup the server to have a mysql database so other local machines can connect to it.  Is it best to achieve this by installing PHP, MySQL, Apache etc. separately or to use something like wampserver?

I figured wampserver would be the straightforward approach but doesn't using a virtual server on a server defeat the purpose of it?  Basically looking for some direction or a link here as I am completely clueless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAMP server basically packages those different programs together and gives you things like a program icon, a system tray icon to control servers, readymade links to say phpMyAdmin. The underlying servers are the same as the 'original' ones. As such you may find WAMP server easier to install AND easier to administer.

Downside - the WAMP server does NOT includes latest 'originals'. They latest originals make it to WAMP server distribution with some lag. If you need latest say PHP, then better off installing them on your own.

Answer (score 1):

WAMP server is a collection of Apache, Mysql and PHP modules.

WAMP server is same as having each component installed separately, 
however WAMP server gives you a package that is very user friendly in terms of quick shortcuts like (starting/stopping server, activating modules ans so on) which you would have to do manually (by editing config files if installed separately)

**Pros of WAMP**

- Userfriendly
- Easy to activate/ desactivate modules
- Additional features (phpmyadmin,sqlbuddy etc..)

**Cons**

- Difficult to upgrade
- Securitiy issues
- Performance issues